# Mysql > get cars and cars-stocks data for specific date but if cars-stocks is not exist on specific date then show only cars data with null stocks

Tags: mysql, left-join, stock

I have created a system where I have two tables namely cars and car stocks.
Cars table stores the list of cars that the dealer sells and Car stocks table stores the no. of cars for each car that has at least one piece in stock.
Please suggest a SQL query which gives two rows namely 'Car name' and 'No. of cars in stock'. **car_name** and **car_stock_qty**
For a car that has zero stock , Null should be written on the second column .

I have tried below query, which works fine for smaller data, but takes too much time for larger data.

Query:

```
SELECT cars.id,
cars.name,
car_stocks.created_at
FROM `cars`
LEFT JOIN car_stocks ON car_stocks.car_id = cars.id and date(car_stocks.created_at) = '2022-01-18';
```

Example expected result:

[image]

Please suggest if you have a more optimized/less time consuming query

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating an index for the `car_stock` ID and `created_at`, I think that's as fast as you can get.

Comment: Those fields already have indexing